# Does Spark streaming process every JSON "event" individually when reading from Kafka?

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I want to use Spark streaming to read from a single Kafka topic messages in JSON format, however not all the events have similar schema.  If possible, what's the best way to check each event's schema and process it accordingly?

Is it possible to group in memory several groups each made of a bunch of similar schema events and then process each group as a bulk?

Comment: I would suggest 1) using a similar schema for every message in a topic 2) Avro can help you better than JSON with that

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't do. You need somehow to decode your JSON message to identify the schema and this would be done in your Spark code. However you can try to populate the Kafka message key with a different value per schema and get assign Spark partitions per key.

Answer (score 0):

Object formats like parquet and avro are good for this reason since the schema is available in the header. If you absolutely must use JSON then you can do as you said and use group-by-key while casting to the object you want. If you are using large JSON objects then you will see a performance hit since the entire JSON "file" must be parsed before any objects resolution can take place.